# Java Port Scanner to identify the service running

Tags: java, port, port-scanning

I have recently built a port scanner using Java, it is for my university course (just so you know I'm not doing it for malicious reasons). Now we have been assigned to make it recognise which service is running on each port that is listening, I believe that each port will send a response header when it an application tries to connect to it, and I think that from this header it is possible to understand which application is running on it, unless it has been manually overridden.
I am struggling to retrieve this header, and even then I am unsure what to actually do with it. I am sorry this is such a broad question, I am new to programming altogether. 
Any links or information you could share with me would be much appreciated. I did look through other questions but couldn't see one similar to my problem, I'm sorry if I missed it.

Thanks in Advance.

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {


    Socket socket;
    String message="";
    try {

        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 3306),1000);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        if (br.readLine()!=null){
             message += br.readLine();
             if (message!=null){
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show us [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now we have been assigned to make it recognise which service is running on each port that is listening

I don't believe your task is computationally feasible, unless you are allowed to lookup /etc/services.

> I believe that each port will send a response header when it an application tries to connect to it

No. Telnet and HTTP for example send nothing until a request is received.

> I am sorry this is such a broad question

It's not your fault, it's the fault of the assignment, unless you have misunderstood it or misquoted it here.

Comment: I have added the code I have so far to the orginal post, I am getting a text response with some legible text, although I am unsure if it is correct as for a header. I am testing it on port 3306 (MySQL) and it returns the following as text 
"5.6.11ÏM\dcBa@]ˇ˜Ä500?,[hyG7z#mysql_native_password"

Comment: Is the assignment limited to what is running on some specific computer? and to those services where the conversation starts with a prompt from the server? If not I still don't see how this is computationally feasible. Identifying one MySQL server on port 3306 is nice, but at this rate you will have graduated, or not, before the assignment is complete. You need to ask your professors these questions. Produce this exchange and ask for comments.

Comment: I will ask him tomorrow, thank you very much for your time and the help you have provided so far, I have normally managed to find some bits and pieces to get started with using google but this time the information seemed very limited, hence why I asked it on here. Again thank you for your help so far. :)

Comment: I have spoken with my Teacher and I would appear that I have mis-understood the requirements of the homework! I am sorry for asking irrelevant questions, we are building a program that will attempt to connect to a DB remotely, asking for the username and password and I thought we had to identify which port the DB Was running on, but it seems that we can just check the default ports. So my question is null and void. Thank you very much for your time and again sorry.